# Camel unmarshal Rest response exception

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm facing an issue with unmarshalling response from Rest call

My camel-context.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-2.8.3.xsd">

    <bean class="com.myapp.MyProcessor" id="myResponseProcessor"/>

    <camelContext id="camelId" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <camel:route id="myServiceCreate">
            <!-- SKIPPING PREPARATION PART -->
            <log message="BODY ----- ${body}"/>
            <marshal>
                <json library="Jackson"/>
            </marshal>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="{{services.myuri}}/create"/>
            <log message="Message: ${body}"></log>
            <unmarshal>
                <json library="Jackson"  unmarshalTypeName="com.myapp.MyPojo"/>
            </unmarshal>
            <process id="_processMyResponse" ref="myResponseProcessor"/>
        </camel:route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

As a result I get an exception

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@68de2df1; line: 1, column: 0]
```

I've tried adding a cast to String:

```
  <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
```

but it caused exception with BufferedStream.

Logs show that a response is ok:

```
17:13:25.532 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1] INFO  myServiceCreate - Message: {"collectionId":"123"}
```

How can I fix unmarshalling?

Comment: as you unmarshal by POJO, can you also paste it? does it match with the JSON?

Comment: checkout the Edit section in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590193/setting-rest-response-body-in-camel/48590651#48590651.

Comment: @Kepotx, Pojo is ok public class MyPojo {
    @JsonProperty("collectionId")
    private String collectionId;}

Comment: @pvpkiran, tyried adding following. With  no avail                  <setHeader headerName="Accept"><constant>application/json</constant></setHeader>

Comment: Where in the route did you add the cast to String? Before or after the logging?

Comment: @noMad17, after.

Comment: @noMad17, removed logs, unmarshalling started working! But I need logs... Any idea how to achieve both?

Answer (score 1):

The reason unmarshalling started working after you removed the logging is because the body is of the type `InputStream` which means the stream will be flushed after accessing it the first time, which in this case would be the log.

If, as you say, you need to have logging then add the cast to String *before* logging, i.e. immediately after `to`.

```
<to uri="{{services.myuri}}/create"/>
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
<log message="Message: ${body}"></log>
<unmarshal>
    <json library="Jackson"  unmarshalTypeName="com.myapp.MyPojo"/>
</unmarshal>
```

**Edit**

I also found [this](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html) FAQ which explains this phenomenon.